# Deep linking with branch.io stop for Twitter and facebook other other social network it works fine

Tags: android, branch.io

Suddenly deep linking stop working for facebook and twitter. Previously it works fine.

Here is my manifest code :

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="live-key" />

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <data android:scheme="05media.com" android:host="open" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="05media2.app.link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="05media2-alternate.app.link" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Also i enable custom search and add package name ( com.pinmedia.mediaguide ).
Same use in manifest
Also add SHA256 Cert Fingerprints.

I searched for that but nothing can work for me

Please help me why this is not working for twitter and facebook. For other it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

I see that you have only one intent filter which is setup for both app links and regular deep links. You should instead define two separate intent filters in your Android Manifest as follows:

```
<!-- Config for Deeplink -->
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="05media.com" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>

<!-- Config for App Links -->
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="05media2.app.link" />
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="05media2-alternate.app.link" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can check out the Android manifest for one of the Sample App here: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-Example-Deep-Linking-Branchster-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L34

If you continue to face issues I would suggest writing to: integrations@branch.io. They will be able to work with you one on one.

**Credit to Evan Groth for this response.**

Comment: Thanks for you effort but this will not resolve my issue. Result is the same.